# Mystery Interface and Routes on ipsec0, Catalina OSX

Tags: network-interface, routing, vpn, macos, pptp

Any clue what is causing the `ipsec0` interface to establish PTP and then adding a default route to the PTP?

It's borking my routing and I can't seem to find the culprit

I have no VPN profiles enabled, no VPN client running.
Recently removed ProtonVPN. 
TunnelBlick installed but not running.

This seems to happen each time I connect to a WiFi AP.

`ifconfig -a -vv ipsec0` -- Note the `agent domain desc:"VPN: ProtonVPN"` [**App Cleaner used to remove ProtonVPN several times]**

```
ipsec0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1400 index 17
    eflags=5002080<TXSTART,NOAUTOIPV6LL,ECN_ENABLE,CHANNEL_DRV>
    xflags=4<NOAUTONX>
    options=6403<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    inet 10.6.5.206 --> 10.6.5.206 netmask 0xff000000 
    netif: E22A3DA9-EA52-41DE-9C1F-5F4598DEF26F
    flowswitch: E79F3C2B-56E4-4816-B390-7DB240E9664E
    type: 0x1 family: 18 subfamily: 0
    functional type: wifi
    agent domain:Skywalk type:NetIf flags:0x8443 desc:"Userspace Networking"
    agent domain:Skywalk type:FlowSwitch flags:0x4403 desc:"Userspace Networking"
    agent domain:NetworkExtension type:VPN flags:0xf desc:"VPN: ProtonVPN"
    link quality: -1 (unknown)
    state availability: 0 (true)
    scheduler: FQ_CODEL 
    effective interface: en0
    qosmarking enabled: no mode: none
    low power mode: disabled
    multi layer packet logging (mpklog): disabled
```

`netstat -nr`

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            link#17            UCS         ipsec0       
default            192.168.16.1       UGScI          en0       
1.2.3.4            link#17            UHW3I       ipsec0     29
3.82.239.106       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
3.228.164.50       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
10.6.5.206         10.6.5.206         UH          ipsec0       
10.6.9.1           link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
13.107.136.9       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
17.57.144.20       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
17.248.129.42      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
17.248.129.106     link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
17.248.188.11      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
18.204.158.139     link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
23.36.192.188      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
23.36.193.63       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.192.122.34      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.202.13.87       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.204.122.179     link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.214.40.205      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.224.73.75       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.228.110.91      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
34.235.232.2       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
50.19.197.254      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.2.223.38        link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.2.231.4         link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.38.182.237      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.96.36.82        link#17            UHW3I       ipsec0     29
52.96.39.162       link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.113.194.132     link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.114.88.28       link#17            UHW3I       ipsec0     35
52.114.132.22      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.114.132.38      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.114.133.12      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.114.142.157     link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
52.204.83.172      link#17            UHWIi       ipsec0       
54.84.147.205      link#17            UHW3I       ipsec0     33
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#6             UCS            en0      !
172.16.215/24      link#19            UC          vmnet8      !
172.16.215.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI      vmnet8      !
172.83.43.134      192.168.16.1       UGHS           en0       
192.168.16/22      link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.16.1/32    link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.16.1       f0:9f:c2:1a:63:cf  UHLWIir        en0   1187
192.168.16.66      9c:30:5b:d3:77:2f  UHLWI          en0   1138
192.168.16.69      0:b3:62:34:7b:de   UHLWI          en0    877
192.168.16.124     c4:61:8b:4c:ec:5f  UHLWI          en0   1057
192.168.16.133     c8:3c:85:a0:2f:b7  UHLWI          en0    814
192.168.16.155     2c:be:8:bb:5e:c3   UHLWI          en0    825
192.168.16.201     80:82:23:66:84:4   UHLWI          en0    877
192.168.16.219     0:15:99:d7:f6:5a   UHLWI          en0   1185
192.168.16.225     c:51:1:c7:a4:1e    UHLWI          en0    856
192.168.16.234/32  link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.16.236     0:80:92:cb:ab:bf   UHLWI          en0   1180
192.168.17.8       6c:8d:c1:3f:b5:2d  UHLWI          en0   1079
192.168.17.16      d8:1c:79:ea:8e:2b  UHLWI          en0    911
192.168.17.65      90:e1:7b:d7:75:23  UHLWI          en0   1007
192.168.17.67      34:2:86:87:d1:b    UHLWI          en0   1069
192.168.17.85      d8:1c:79:ca:6b:bd  UHLWI          en0   1176
192.168.17.173     14:20:5e:85:36:2   UHLWI          en0   1031
192.168.17.221     38:b1:db:e3:40:3b  UHLWIi         en0   1165
192.168.17.222     30:d1:6b:10:93:c0  UHLWI          en0   1079
192.168.18.6       c0:a6:0:7:ee:c9    UHLWI          en0    857
192.168.18.69      8c:85:90:11:5c:90  UHLWI          en0   1094
192.168.18.79      40:bc:60:1e:2:d5   UHLWI          en0    967
192.168.18.124     7c:a1:ae:8:29:8f   UHLWI          en0   1066
192.168.18.161     34:42:62:7d:a7:d0  UHLWI          en0   1124
192.168.18.189     14:10:9f:e9:31:a2  UHLWIi         en0   1163
192.168.18.239     3c:2e:ff:1f:94:ca  UHLWI          en0   1138
192.168.19.2       58:6b:14:6:b5:9e   UHLWI          en0    931
192.168.19.22      54:33:cb:51:60:53  UHLWIi         en0    813
192.168.19.76      80:c:67:3f:2c:e1   UHLWI          en0    988
192.168.19.83      b0:ca:68:9c:83:3c  UHLWI          en0    924
192.168.19.143     b8:41:a4:54:c0:8a  UHLWIi         en0    874
192.168.19.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI         en0      !
192.168.74         link#18            UC          vmnet1      !
192.168.74.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI      vmnet1      !
224.0.0/4          link#17            UmCS        ipsec0       
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCSI          en0      !
224.0.0.251        link#17            UHmW3I      ipsec0     33
255.255.255.255/32 link#17            UCS         ipsec0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCSI           en0      !

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0       
default                                 fe80::%utun1                    UGcI          utun1       
default                                 fe80::%utun2                    UGcI          utun2       
default                                 fe80::%utun3                    UGcI          utun3       
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0       
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0       
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%en10/64                          link#4                          UCI            en10       
fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en10          ac:de:48:0:11:22                UHLI            lo0       
fe80::aede:48ff:fe33:4455%en10          ac:de:48:33:44:55               UHLWIi         en10       
fe80::%en0/64                           link#6                          UCI             en0       
fe80::3:aea3:bd6f:3c20%en0              78:31:c1:c7:8a:ac               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::45:ff77:829e:1285%en0             8c:85:90:98:cd:34               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::6d:c188:a11c:8f03%en0             9c:20:7b:de:7:a7                UHLWI           en0       
fe80::4cb:eb4c:daae:2b54%en0            b8:17:c2:c1:77:3a               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::4d1:99e4:6833:564%en0             a4:83:e7:5e:75:e1               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::8e0:d15f:bde0:dc04%en0            98:1:a7:a4:a6:1b                UHLWI           en0       
fe80::8f6:451f:1b75:721e%en0            f8:ff:c2:2e:ca:73               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::ca8:73fd:44fe:228a%en0            f8:ff:c2:44:e9:44               UHLI            lo0       
fe80::cf5:61:515f:c450%en0              10:94:bb:ed:2c:18               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::108b:8810:1b67:3c89%en0           8c:85:90:11:5c:90               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::10b4:36dc:d9c9:990f%en0           88:e9:fe:5c:21:19               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::1438:8686:40a6:4389%en0           b0:34:95:3d:7a:59               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::1493:6a8f:4a22:4454%en0           68:db:ca:9e:83:95               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::14a6:911:68f6:a4b8%en0            38:f9:d3:5a:8d:5b               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::180f:3b62:489b:7928%en0           38:f9:d3:b6:32:59               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::18bc:cdbc:550:64e0%en0            6c:8d:c1:3f:b5:2d               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::18ee:81f3:88fd:51d9%en0           a4:83:e7:83:f4:69               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::1cdb:e916:7bf8:8d4f%en0           38:f9:d3:cd:a0:28               UHLWI           en0       
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#8                          UCI           awdl0       
fe80::6c52:f6ff:fe27:30de%awdl0         6e:52:f6:27:30:de               UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%llw0/64                          link#9                          UCI            llw0       
fe80::6c52:f6ff:fe27:30de%llw0          6e:52:f6:27:30:de               UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%utun0/64                         fe80::ef8d:39b7:d0a7:bcff%utun0 UcI           utun0       
fe80::ef8d:39b7:d0a7:bcff%utun0         link#15                         UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%utun1/64                         fe80::f855:da2f:9165:598b%utun1 UcI           utun1       
fe80::f855:da2f:9165:598b%utun1         link#16                         UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%utun2/64                         fe80::c8b3:a4f3:ff43:d729%utun2 UcI           utun2       
fe80::c8b3:a4f3:ff43:d729%utun2         link#20                         UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%utun3/64                         fe80::8a6d:ce1a:3267:fdcb%utun3 UcI           utun3       
fe80::8a6d:ce1a:3267:fdcb%utun3         link#21                         UHLI            lo0       
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0       
ff01::%en10/32                          link#4                          UmCI           en10       
ff01::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI            en0       
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0       
ff01::%llw0/32                          link#9                          UmCI           llw0       
ff01::%utun0/32                         fe80::ef8d:39b7:d0a7:bcff%utun0 UmCI          utun0       
ff01::%utun1/32                         fe80::f855:da2f:9165:598b%utun1 UmCI          utun1       
ff01::%utun2/32                         fe80::c8b3:a4f3:ff43:d729%utun2 UmCI          utun2       
ff01::%utun3/32                         fe80::8a6d:ce1a:3267:fdcb%utun3 UmCI          utun3       
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0       
ff02::%en10/32                          link#4                          UmCI           en10       
ff02::%en0/32                           link#6                          UmCI            en0       
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0       
ff02::%llw0/32                          link#9                          UmCI           llw0       
ff02::%utun0/32                         fe80::ef8d:39b7:d0a7:bcff%utun0 UmCI          utun0       
ff02::%utun1/32                         fe80::f855:da2f:9165:598b%utun1 UmCI          utun1       
ff02::%utun2/32                         fe80::c8b3:a4f3:ff43:d729%utun2 UmCI          utun2       
ff02::%utun3/32                         fe80::8a6d:ce1a:3267:fdcb%utun3 UmCI          utun3
```

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a service from launchd described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384800/how-can-i-track-down-the-process-that-started-a-vpn-interface-on-catalina/384813#384813
...but not having any luck finding the exact service responsible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a remnant config from a ProtonVPN uninstall. Here's the steps I followed to fix it (provided by ProtonVPN support):

```
- Download the latest ProtonVPN application version through the following link: https://protonvpn.com/download/ProtonVPN.dmg
- Install the application, login, establish a connection to a ProtonVPN server, disconnect
- Navigate to macOS System preferences -> Network -> select the ProtonVPN profile and then click on the "-" minus sign to remove it
- Download the uninstaller: https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/
- Install and open it
- Find ProtonVPN application on your device
- Drag and drop ProtonVPN application to the app cleaner
- Once it is deleted, clear your trash bin

Continue with the following:

- Navigate to your WiFi settings and remove/forget the Wi-Fi network you are connected to
- Reboot your device
- Select the WiFi network and enter the authentication information again
- Check if the issue persists and inform us of the results
```